# Using same X and Y axis for all par() plots

Tags: r

I have a loop generating 15 plots, one for each of my `factor` variables. This is my first time using `par()` to set up the plot space (I usually use ggplot or lattice, which I probably should have done here). Anyway, I'm generally okay with this, but I would like each graph to have the same X and Y range (1,5) and (0,120), respectively. I've read the `?par` documentation but haven't figured out how to  accomplish this. Here is my code:

```
par(mar=c(2,2,2,2),mfrow = c(4, 4))
for (i in 2:16) {
  plot(df[,i], main=colnames(df)[i],
       ylab = "Count", col="steelblue", las = 2)
}
```

Comment: `plot(..., xim=c(1,5), ylim=c(0,120)` - the limits of the plotting area are set by `plot()`, not `par()`

Comment: I've tried that... it worked for the y axis but shifted my x bars far to the left and did not make space for the 1 bar when n = 0, if that makes sense.

Comment: Oh, you have `factor` columns. I think you need to do `df[] <- lapply(df, factor, levels=1:5)` first, so every category in `1:5` is shown in your output.

Comment: Ah. Yes! I had the `df[] <- lapply(df, factor, levels=1:5)` call, but I'd left out the levels argument. That did the trick. Thank you. I think I'll happily go back to ggplot (which I know a lot better) now. Haha.